# indexeddb get all keys from object store

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb, persistent-object-store

I'm new to indexeddb.
Let's say I put several objects to indexed db:

```
transaction.objectStore("some_store").put(some_object, some_key);
```

Now I want to get all keys from that object store. Is that possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

Possible as Kristof said by using openCursor method. It is not efficient because requesting value cursor object *might* involve de-serialization.

You should also note that, your put method return primary key of the inserted object.

Currently, if you want very efficient keys retrive, index the keyPath for in-line key object store. For out-of-line object store you are out of luck. Using index, you can retrive keys as follow:

```
transaction.objectStore("some_store").index('id').openKeyCursor(); // here id is primary key path
```

There is a [bug report](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=19955) for requesting openKeyCursor method directly object store. Hopefully next IndexedDB spec will have it.

Comment: Looks like that bug report [have been updated](https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/commit/0f168cc96e38441b9131124786992589fbdb0388) last January.

Answer (score 2):

There is a **IDBObjectStore.getAllKeys()** method, which will return all keys from an object store.

For more information about this method see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/getAllKeys

You could use this together with the **IDBObjectStore.getAll()** method to combine the results.

The drawback is that no data should be added to the store between executing those methods.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the openCursor method to retrieve al records 1 by 1. Only getting the keys isn't possible.

Comment: And I was asking about keys, not values.

Comment: I know, but it isn't possible without using an index, but putting an index on an keypath of an object store isn't the best idea if you ask me. Bur you can do it like kyaw sais